# Spacing between list of algorithms inconsisten

Tags: pdftex, algorithm2e

Unfortunately, when increasing the parskip amount, the distance between two lines in the list of algorithms is increased. This is not the case for the list of figures and tables. I would like to remove the extra space in the list of algorithms without decreasing the parskip (which I use to get extra space between some paragraphs).

The following is a minimal working example (with some compile error :-():

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}

\setlength\parskip{\bigskipamount}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,norelsize]{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listofalgorithms



      \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \center{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
        {figures/biotensor.png}}
        \caption{\label{fig:my-label} My figure.  An example of a cool figure}
      \end{figure}

          \begin{figure}[!htb]
        \center{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]
        {figures/biotensor.png}}
        \caption{\label{fig:my-label} My figure.  An example of a cool figure}
      \end{figure}




\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm 1}\label{alg:1}
  $q \leftarrow 0$ \tcc*[r]{column offset}
    asdasd
 \end{algorithm}


\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm 2}\label{alg:2}
  $q \leftarrow 0$ \tcc*[r]{column offset}
    asdasd
 \end{algorithm}
\begin{algorithm

\end{document}
```

This is the inconsistency I'm talking about:

[image: Inconsistency in spacing between list of algorithms and figures]

Comment: Why not modify `\parskip` after  `\listofalgorithms`

Comment: You're right, of course!
I somehow didn't think of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the `\parskip` after the the `\listofalgorithms`.

You should also include the `graphicx`-package, otherwise the `\includegraphics`-commands will throw an error.

In the `figure`-environment, you should use the `\label`-command after you have used the `\caption`-command.  Funnily, on the `algorithm`-environments, do have it the correct way.

I don't know, what your editor is using, mine is using UTF-8 by default.  This is not working with the `algoritms`-package.  Therefore, you should define

```
\usepackage[latin1]{fontenc}
```

or something similar in your preamble.

I think, that have been all replacements.

EDIT: one more hint: don't specify the file extension for `\includegraphics` unless you really have to.  Assuming, that your files have unique names, you can leave the `.png`, LaTeX will find the file itself and not complain.  If you are not sure, you will compile your file with pdfLaTeX, you can make PostScript copy of your files (that is, the same filename but ending in `.ps` or `.eps`) and still are able to compile the LaTeX file without any changes in the source code.

Here is the working MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered,norelsize]{algorithm2e} 


\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listofalgorithms
\clearpage
\setlength\parskip{\bigskipamount}


\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}
  \caption{My figure.  An example of a cool figure}
  \label{fig:my-label}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-golden}
  \caption{My figure.  An example of a cool figure}
  \label{fig:my-label2}
\end{figure}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm 1}\label{alg:1}
  $q \leftarrow 0$ \tcc*[r]{column offset}
  asdasd
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Algorithm 2}\label{alg:2}
  $q \leftarrow 0$ \tcc*[r]{column offset}
  asdasd
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```